# Jenkins Priority Sorter Plugin - How to use BuildPriority Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to dynamically apply priorities (from 1 to 5) to Jenkins jobs started via a URL containing the BuildPriority parameter.

In the Priority Sorter Config I selected

->Use additional rules when assigning a priority to a Job

and chose "Use Priority from Build Parameter" as Build Strategy.

I left Build Parameter Name = "BuildPriority".

Starting the Job via:

```
http://localhost:8080/job/myJobName/buildWithParameters?PARAM1=value1&PARAM2=value2&BuildPriority=1
```

doesn't apply the priority. I tried to add a string Parameter to the Job named "BuildPriority" which didn't work as well. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

marcus

**Update:**

I found this related Bug already tracked:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22294

**Update 2:**
For those searching for a solution I can offer a workaround:
Allow parallel builds for the corresponding job and reduce the number of processors/cores in Jenkins settings to 1. If this is not an option for you, as you want to use all cores, install Throttle Concurrent Builds Plug-in which allows you to "throttle" every Job on its own to as many cores as you want.
Throttling to 1 and allowing parallel builds got me the behaviour I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Priority Sorter Plugin (as of Plugin Version 3.6.0 with Jenkins 2.73.3) will be prevented from even "seeing" a queue for a *single* Job, unless the option `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` is checked.

Therefore: Allow parallel builds for the corresponding job and reduce the number of processors/cores in Jenkins settings to 1. If this is not an option for you, as you want to use all cores, install [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents) which allows you to "throttle" every Job on its own to as many cores as you want. Throttling to `1` *and* allowing parallel builds got me the behaviour I expected.

Comment: Marcus, check the option "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" did the trick for me. I spent a whole day on this till I found this link. Thanks a lot.