# jenkins - give priority to all downstream jobs over job in queue

Tags: jenkins

I have a scenario where a jenkins job X is executing on a node, which has a downstream job Y to be executed on the same node. Also when the first job is executing, i have another job Z in the queue for this node.

I want Y to execute after X has executed. Currently, the job in queue(Z) is excuting after X, and the downstream job is being put on queue.

Also, I do not want X to wait until Y has finished.

How can i do this?

Comment: Hey @sparrow It's been a while, but I'm in the same boat as you now. Have you found a solution to this problem yet? If you have, I'd really appreciate it if you could share it with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all possible way in Priority sorter plugin. But I couldn't achieve your requirement.

I found below links during my research. Hope it helps you.
Let me know if it works.

[Jenkins Priority Sorter Plugin - How to use BuildPriority Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145115/jenkins-priority-sorter-plugin-how-to-use-buildpriority-parameter)

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/priority-sorter-plugin-tp4692827p4706187.html

The links say, you can achieve priority based execution by allowing jobs in parallel/concurrent mode

Comment: thank you so much for trying. I changed the design to prevent this situation from happening, as I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger job Z after job Y is executed.

Or if you would like to add priorities to your jobs, you could give that plugin a try:

[Priority sorter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin)

Comment: hi, i already have another job Z in queue, which is not in my control. I tried using this plugin, but it turns out it works only if both jobs are in queue at the same time. but the job Z is getting executed before the downstream job Y is getting into queue. So, sorting according to priority is not happening in this case

Comment: Have you tried Absolute priority?

''Each Job will be assigned a Priority, the lower the Priority the sooner the Job will be run.''

Comment: Yes i did. I gave the downstream job a lower priority, than the job in queue. But even then the job is queue was executed first. I think this is because, jenkins resolves priority only if both jobs are in queue at the same time. But in this case, the downstream is not in queue while the job Z is in queue. so it cannot resolve according to priority